# How do I use 2 modified feed templates?

Tags: rss

I've been using an added function to load a modified rss template.
Works fine, but now I need to add a custom template for a CPT.

I have code for each,which works ok, but can't be used together because one over-rides the other.

I don't know enough php to modify.

Here's the code I'm using...

```
remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', function() {
if ( $rss_template = locate_template( '/feeds/notes-feed.php' ) )
load_template( $rss_template );
else
do_feed_rss2(); // Call default function
}, 10, 1 );
```

and

```
remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'item_feed_rss2', 10, 1 );
function item_feed_rss2() {
$rss_template = get_template_directory() . '/feeds/item-feed.php';
if( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'item' and file_exists(      $rss_template ) )
load_template( $rss_template );
else
do_feed_rss2(); // Call default function
```

Not knowing enough, I'm wondering if I can use this...

```
remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'item_feed_rss2', 10, 1 );
function item_feed_rss2() {
$rss_template = get_template_directory() . '/feeds/item-feed.php';
$rss_template_notes = get_template_directory() . '/feeds/notes-feed.php';
if( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'item' and file_exists( $rss_template ) )
load_template( $rss_template );
elseif( get_query_var( 'post' ) and file_exists( $rss_template_notes ) )
load_template( $rss_template_notes );
else
do_feed_rss2(); // Call default function
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I’ll add this in case it’s of use to someone.

It seems to work ok with…

```
// This delivers valid feeds, with the correct templates.
remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', function() {
$rss_template = get_template_directory() . '/feeds/item-feed.php';
$rss_template2 = get_template_directory() . '/feeds/notes-feed.php';
//if ( $post_type = 'item'  )
if( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'item' and file_exists($rss_template ) )
load_template($rss_template);
elseif ( $post_type = 'post' )
load_template($rss_template2);
else
do_feed_rss2(); // Call default function
}, 10, 1 );
```

This enables use of a custom template for the feed of normal posts, and use of a different custom template for the feed of the CPT ‘item’.

The feeds differ in channel title/link/description.

Comment: Nothing else worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the logic for the two together. :)

Use a single callback and depending on current context override with either one template or another.

Another option would be to handle differences *inside* the template, not my favorite approach but some prefer it.

Comment: Thanks. My php knowledge is small, so I've tried to use your suggestion and add to the original question.